# OS X serial port open with DTR low

Tags: macos, serial-port

I've written serial port access code for Windows and OS X but on the latter I've yet to find a way to open the port with DTR low.  (I'm trying to avoid reseting my Arduino.) Here is the simplest version of my C code that demonstrates the problem:

```
const char *pathname = "/dev/tty.usbmodem411";
….
int main()
{ 
    int fd;
    int status;
    printf(" STARTING SERIAL PORT PROGRAM \n");
    fd = open(pathname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); 
    if (fd != -1) printf(" port successfully opened, fd = %d\n",fd) ;
    else
    {
        printf(" could not open port\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("closing port and quitting app\n");
    if (fd !=-1) close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't found any other open() flags that help.  I can successfully set DTR low after opening the port via ioctl() but that doesn't help since the Arduino is resetting on open().

Does anyone know how to keep DTR low during open() ?  Could this be a function of the USB driver?

Comment: I asked this question of the company that supplies the USB hardware and driver and got this answer:"This [setting the DTR] will be controlled by the driver when enumerating the device and when opening the port but can be set by the application immediately after opening the port by the application software."  I take this to mean that there is no way to force DTR low before the port is opened.